# React-Native FBSDK LoginButton crashes app in iOS only

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-login, fbsdk

I'm setting up react-native-fbsdk on my app and I was able to configure everything and fix all the errors that showed up, but now whenever I click the LoginButton from FBSDK my app crashes in iOS, but in Android everything works fine.

This is what I tried to do:

- Changing `publishPermissions to readPermissions;`
- Adding `#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>` in AppDelegate.m
- Upgraded the iOS SDK to v4.31.0 and changed the info.plist

to:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>000000000000</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>AppName</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

- Reinstalled fbsdk package from 0.

The behaviour is the same without any errors on debug mode.

What else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Whats the version of xcode you are using? Did you try to run using xcode and check the debug console?

Comment: I'm using version 9.2 of xcode.
I ran xcode like you said and got the following error: "reason: 'fb172231600071063 is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist'"

Comment: Try to add this value in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes section of your info.plist. I ran the same problem a few days ago.

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
  ...
  <string> fb172231600071063 </string>
    </array>
</array>

Maybe the error will persist but with a different value. Just go ahead and insert what xcode is asking.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, that actually fixed my problem. I was following a old guide that didn't had that step. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Adding @Rafael Motta answer to my info.plist fixed my problem:

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>fb[app-id]</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```